# How to use indexOf in kotlin for ArrayList of a data class?

Tags: kotlin

In `kotlin`, I have a `data class` like this:

```
data class MyModel (
    val key: String,
    val myValue: String
)
```

I have an `ArrayList` of above model:

```
val myList: ArrayList<MyModel>
```

I don't know how to get the index of an element by passing the key:

```
fun getPosition(key: String): Int = myList.indexOf(/* what to do here? */)
```

----edit----

Assume that keys are unique.

Comment: what if there are multiple entries with the same key?

Comment: the keys are unique in the required case

Comment: might be easier to work with a map then

Comment: I am implementing `ItemKeyProvider` in `RecyclerView` in `android`, for that I needed to know this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `indexOfFirst` which receive a functional parameter:

```
fun getPosition(key: String): Int = myList.indexOfFirst { it.key == key }
```